# symbolic function doesn't return value even when passed parameters?

Tags: symbolic-math

```
syms h(x)
h(x)=cos(x)^2+sin(x)^2
```

when I try `h(10,10)`, it will return the answer as `cos(10)^2 + sin(10)^2`

why am I not getting the answer as 1?

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstand, but you don't use the `y` in `h(x,y)`? Also, if this is matlab you should tag it as such.

Comment: redundant variable, forgive me. despite that why do I not get the answer as 1 ?

Comment: I have little experience in MATLAB, so all I can say is that you'll probably want to have a little look at the subs function (setting x to a symbolic variable and defining h separately).